# How to use barcode scanner to send data to PC using WiFi

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to store the UPC to your Android device, (excel or notepad) after scanning, and be able to send it to PC via WiFi? And make the data directly go into notepad or excel?

I'm developing an inventory system using the Android WiFi scanner. Please help me because I'm having a hard time searching if this is feasible.

Comment: It's feasable. You will not be able to press a few buttons to make it work however. You will need to roll out a service of your own, and an application to handle the forwarder (scanned) barcodes to the service, which later forwards it to the target computer.

There is no way for you to send data to an opened notepad or excel on teh target computer.

Comment: If you're working on an inventory system, why bother with notepad or excel? Why not send it directly to your inventory database?

Comment: thanks...@323go i will used notepad or excel as a storage only..so the sending of data will be batch processed and forwarded to my inventory system, in that case the data will be not mixed up with others..but my problem is i don't know what drivers would help me, and if there's a third party application that can receive data what is it??

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on this exact project for my work!

I downloaded an app called ScanPet! (you will also need to download Barcode Scanner - also free, and you dont need to do anything with the app) It will scan a barcode and automatically store the serial number. You can then input a couple other fields manually like model, price, comments, and a few others. The app stores it all in an excel doc that you can then email to yourself.

If you are using outlook, then its rather easy to scan the inbox, grab the attachment, open it, and then input the data from the excel doc into your database!! As you said, a batch call can be setup to scheduel the task as well!! Best of luck automating friend!

Comment: I can share my code when i eventually build up the rest of the processes!